# Autocomplete (AKA Code Completion) with CodeIgniter libraries and PhpStorm

Tags: php, codeigniter, autocomplete, phpstorm

I have an `autocomplete.php` file in my config directory. Autocomplete works perfectly everywhere *except* in library files. Here is an example of the problem:

```
class Some_custom_lib {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->model('some_custom_model');
    }

    public function createSubrofile($post_vars) {
        return $this->CI->some_custom_model->create_file($post_vars); <-- This will not autocomplete.
    }
```

To be clear, this is a CodeIgniter library file that lives in applications/libraries folder and is loaded with `$this->load->library('Some_custom_lib');`

How can I get autocomplete to work inside CodeIgniter library files with PhpStorm?

Comment: What value is returned by `create_file` function is it `json` or some array data?

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "library" here. Is it listed in PhpStorm in a folder that marked as a library or what?

Comment: @Rohan An array is returned. However, the return value is irrelevant to autocomplete as far as I am aware.

Comment: @LazyOne The file is a library in CodeIgniter terminology. i.e. it is in applications/libraries folder and is loaded with $this->load->library('Some_custom_lib');

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a kind poster over in the CodeIgniter forums, I have the answer for anyone googling this thread. All you need to do is add

```
/*
* @property CI_Controller $CI
*/
```

to the top of the library.